# Jumping Onload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I have a div at the very top of my site that I want to hide and when you click a button it pushes the whole site down and reveals its contents.  Very similar to this [nd.edu](http://nd.edu) (click help center or poplar sites on the right side of the header).  I am using jquery to accomplish this.  This script works but it is jumpy, since the content in the div has to be accessible if JS is turned off, it has to get the height and then hide it.  I'm just looking for a way to make the "drawer" not open than shut when the page is loaded, rather it appears that there is nothing there till you click the link (just like nd.edu).  Any help would be great.

`// Quick Links Slider Effect// Define Vars`
    `var $links = $('#quick_links');`
    `var height = $links.height();`

`// Set the height of #quick_links to 0
    $links.hide().css({height: 0});`

```
// When slide is click kick of the function
$(".slide").click(function(){
    // If its visible aniamate to 0
    if($links.is(":visible")){
        $links.animate({height: "0"}, {duration: 300, complete: function(){
            $links.hide();
        }
        });
    }
    // Else animate the height down
    else {
        $links.show().animate({height : height}, {duration: 300});
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here is my html and css

```
        #quick_links{background:url(../images/drawer_shadow.jpg) bottom left repeat-x #F6F8F7;width:100%; padding-bottom:20px; position:relative; z-index:1;}
#quick_links ul{float:left !important;margin:0 20px 0 20px;}
#quick_links_button{float:right;background:url(../images/umflint-sprite.png) -430px -132px  no-repeat;height:24px;width:101px;text-indent:-9999px;}
<div id="quick_links">
      <div class="wrapper">
                 <h3>
                    Quicklinks
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Stuff Goes Here</li>
                </ul>

            </div><!-- End Wrapper -->
          </div><!-- End QuickLinks -->
           <a href="#quick_links" class="slide" id="quick_links_button" name="quick_links_button">Quick Links</a>
         <div id="content">
               blah blah blah
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`$.slideDown()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown) instead of animating to the height. As for hiding it when the document loads:

```
$(function(){
  $("#quick-links").hide();
});
```

To hide it:

```
$("#quick-links").slideDown(300);
```

And to show it:

```
$("#quick-links").slideUp(300);
```

Comment: So should I replace these in the conditional statement or scraper the conditional and just use .toggle() to fire off the slides?

Comment: You could use the conditional, if you like. Or you could use `$.slideToggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer is good, but will only hide the div after Jquery is loaded. If that's still not early enough for you, you could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#hiddenbox {display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this will write the hidden box for people that have JS enabled
    document.write("<div id='hiddenbox'>stuff goes here</div>");
</script>
<noscript>
    <!-- this will write the visible box for people that have JS disabled -->
    <div id='alternatebox'>stuff goes here</div>
</noscript>
```

This would insert your hidden box only if the person has JS active, otherwise it would insert a visible box.

Comment: -1 | From the OP: **the content in the div has to be accessible if JS is turned off**

Comment: Yes--what I mean is the content is duplicated--one div has an ID that causes it to be hidden on load via CSS, the other alternate box (for no JS) has the same content, but the ID in that case does not have a CSS rule to hide the content on load, so it shows up as visible for people with no JS.

Comment: Did you try the code Jonathan? Here's an explanation of the noscript tag if you aren't familiar with it: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp -- I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: can we please stop using `document.write();` we are past these times.